# Intuitionistic Linear Logic

Tags: logic, reference-request, proof-theory, constructive-mathematics, linear-logic

I am currently going through some papers that use the "intuitionistic version" of Girard's Linear Logic. The problem is that I seem to find very little literature on it. There is a lot done on Linear Logic but I specifically wanted some introduction to its intuitionistic version (why did it come up, historical context, etc.). Any recommendations would be helpful!

Comment: Sílvia? xD${{}}$

Comment: indeed! do i know you...?

Comment: Doesn't my nickname ring a bell? ^_^ Hint: I played chess today.

Comment: ha, i know who you are! (sorry about the delay. and about your chess game :P) but i am clueless about your nickname anyway...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Jean-Yves Girard, *Linear Logic* (1987) and A.S.Troelstra, [*Lectures on Linear Logic*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0937073776) (1992).

See also in *SEP* the entry on [Linear Logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-linear/).